# Search by Title

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I cannot get any results by making calls such as https://api.projectoxford.ai/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Ti=='Role-based access control models'&model=latest&count=10&offset=0&attributes=Id,Ti,E

However, using the example in https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/academic-knowledge-api/documentation/QueryExpressionSyntax i am getting a result api.projectoxford.ai/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Ti=='indexing by latent semantic analysis'&model=latest&count=10&offset=0&attributes=Id,Ti,E

Comment: You need a subscription key in the URL to use this service.

Comment: Of course i do, i did not post the header subscription key parameter obviously. Read the question again

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your interest in Microsoft cognitive services!

Currently for performance reasons search of titles, author names, affiliations, fields of studies is performed in lower case. All special characters (like: .,?!:+-/ etc.) should be omitted.

Please, try this query:

```
https://api.projectoxford.ai/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Ti=='role based access control models'&model=latest&count=10&offset=0&attributes=Id,Ti
```

Output should be:

```
{
    "expr": "Ti=='role based access control models'",
    "entities": [
        {
            "logprob": -15.613,
            "Id": 2166602595,
            "Ti": "role based access control models"
        },
        {
            "logprob": -18.504,
            "Id": 1538515919,
            "Ti": "role based access control models"
        },
        {
            "logprob": -22.014,
            "Id": 2000674581,
            "Ti": "role based access control models"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What about something like `https://api.projectoxford.ai/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Ti=='computer'&model=latest&count=10&offset=0&attributes=Id ` which is not returning any results. Should we use W instead of Ti when it comes to title search?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, can you provide a complete list of special characters? Or are we looking for [a-z]. I've noticed that in some instances it is omitted and in other it is replaced with a space. Would be great to get some detail on this. Also, I don't really buy that's it's a performance problem. You can perform a regex replace on those characters pretty quickly.

Comment: for Ti='computer' - there is no publication with title "Computer". This is exact match. Use Ti='computer'... (three dots after 'computer') to find publications with a title starting with a word "computer". You can use W='computer' to find publications which have "computer" word in their title/abstract.

Comment: Maletor - could you provide example with double spaces in title? Let's assume that we have only [a-z] characters in title to make it simple.